# How to add SQL column value here

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, clause

**How can I change the "Name of the Person" mysql column filed "updated_by"?**

```
<?php
$updated_by=$_GET['updated_by'];
$sql = "SELECT * from neonat_patient where updated_by='Name of the Person';";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query-> bindParam(':updated_by', $updated_by, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just few changes replacing 'name of the person' with ? and some changes in bind parameters

```
<?php
$updated_by=$_GET['updated_by'];
$sql = "SELECT * from neonat_patient where updated_by=?";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query-> bindParam(1, $updated_by, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               
?>
```